# Merging dataframes in nested for loops in python

Tags: python

I got many CSV files marked by [factor] and [date]. Each file contains [exposure] for different[symbol]. What I untimately want is for each day, a dataframe contains [symbol] and their [factor]s. Here is what I have tried.

```
for d in tradedays:
    for f in factor_list:
        file_name='/home/jovyan/multifactor_data/'+str(f)+'/'+str(d)+'.csv'
        if os.path.exists(file_name) and 20160929<=int(d)<=20160930:
            origin_df=pd.read_csv(file_name)
            origin_df=origin_df.loc[:,['symbol','indusMkt1']]
            df_list.append(origin_df)
        else:
            pass
```

For this sample, there are 12 different dataframes in the df_list.
I know I can merge dataframe of the same day as

```
M_list=df_list[0]
for i in [1,2,3,4,5]:  
    M_list=M_list.merge(df_list[i],on='symbol')
```

But how can I put that in the loop?
New to python. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: If *df_list* contains 12 different dfs, why in example here you only merge first six?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I was trying to merge all six factors of the same date. df_list contains 12 different dfs, the first six belongs to 20160929, and the latter six belongs to 20160930.

Answer (score 0):

Consider resetting `df_list` within each loop and using `reduce(lambda ...)` to merge all dataframes in a list. And consider using a dictionary with `tradedays` as keys to avoid many daily dataframes in your global environment:

```
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd
import os 

dfs = {}                                                  # MERGED DFs DICT
for d in tradedays:
    df_list = []                                          # RESET DF LIST BY DAY
    for f in factor_list:                    
        file_name = os.path.join('/home/jovyan/multifactor_data',str(f),str(d)+'.csv')
        if os.path.exists(file_name) and 20160929 <= int(d) <= 20160930:
            df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file_name)[['symbol','indusMkt1']])

    dfs[d] = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['symbol']), df_list)
```